# I can't hear my sound after filtering

Tags: matlab, filter-design, butterworth

I am studying on a project which my supervisor gave me this semester. It has multiple steps. Basically, I have my own audio. I added AWGN to this sound using `awgn()` method. SNR is 30. I am trying filters to filter noise in my sound.

What i have done so far is:

```
[sound,Fs] = audioread('C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\sound.m4a');

SNR = 30;

ndata = awgn(sound,SNR);

fft_sound = fft(ndata);

n = 7;
beginFreq = 1000/(Fs/2);
endFreq = 2400/(Fs/2);

[b,a] = butter(n, [beginFreq, endFreq], 'bandpass');
[H,W] = freqz(b,a,n);

fout = filter(b,a,real(fft_sound));
soundsc(fout,Fs);
```

I can hear my sound and also noise with my sound. I want to filter that noise. After using `fft()` i got an error of real and imaginary component of sound. So i wanted to solve the problem using `real()`. But this time I can't hear my sound anymore. All I hear is the noise in the background.

How can i handle with this situation?

Answer (score 2):

A few points

1. You need to filter the time domain signal, not the frequency domain
   signal `fout = filter(b,a,ndata)`
2. You are using `agwn()` incorrectly, at least the SNR will certainly not be 30 dB. I suggest reading the documentation
3. That's a pretty narrow bandpass filter, so there won't be much signal left after filtering. The audio will sound very unnatural.
4. Your filter order is fairly high and using a filter in transfer function representation might create a lot of numerical noise or even instability. Use cascaded second order sections instead.

Comment: "http://ictactjournals.in/paper/IJME_Vol_3_Iss_4_Paper_6_480_487.pdf". This is the study which I am trying to do in Matlab. Do you think I'm doing in the wrong way?